# Qt default "standards" for setupUi

Tags: qt, qt4

From what I have seen, most of Qt tutorials have one main functions called "setupUi" for creating the widgets and the layout for the application.

But, suppose you have a large-scale application that has many widgets, you would end up with a setupUi method that is extremely long, and I would think, very impractical.

My question: Is there any rule, in the deep dark secrets of Qt, that states that someone should define ALL the widgets and ALL the layouts in the setupUi function. Is there are particular reason for this? Or may I split up my layouts into functions that(will be called in setupUi) that contain the components for different sections of my application.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, setupUi() is [usually] used for files generated by `uic` utility from Qt designer forms. There is no such convention
This is what documentation on QWidget says:

> Sets up the user interface for the specified widget.
>
> Note: This function is available with widgets that derive from user
>   interface descriptions created using uic.

I haven't seen any rule specification or such in this case. In fact, I've seen many user-made widgets (without use of Designer) using constructors for basic initialization, or some arbitrary method.

I personally sometimes create widgets on slots and usually don't store pointers to all of them, letting object ownership to do its work - accessing them is not needed almost always.

I try to follow this rule: *write the code that is easy to read and maintain.*
In fact, it is easier for me to have my main window contain few composite widgets, that contain some other composite widgets... each of them being separate logic unit.

Answer (score 2):

Not all Qt applications use that function, that is part of the code that is generated by the tools (starting from the Qt Designer xml), read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) documentation page for more details about how you can use the tools generated C++ code into your code.

So basically for the widgets and layouts that are created using the Designer the setupUi is used to create/setup and layout widgets (that code is generated so you don't need to complicate your life and modify it), but in case you code the widgets and layouts yourself (just code, not using the Designer) you can name functions whatever you like, you can just code all of that into class constructor or separate the code into functions and call only some of those from the constructor or you can even create and layout widgets almost anywhere you like (slots connected to button click or other signals), and also you can write code to add widgets into the Designer layouts.